# How to put another child in startAt and endAt, im trying to put orderbychild but it failed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i having this code for getting my data from firebase in android studio and i want to take the data inside of child that look like this.

This is the realtime database look like and this is my code:
[image]

im trying to use this but it failed when i used the orderByChild

```
Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey()
  .startAt ("*" + tanggalawal)
  .endAt ("*" + tanggalakhir + "\uf8ff")
  .orderByChild ("DataPelanggan");
```

look like this
But the orderByChild cant be used

the thing i need is to take data in the child, i will show in recycleview fragment, this is the full code of my java file

```
public class SearchListView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_search_list_view);

        String tanggalawal = getIntent ( ).getStringExtra ("tanggalawal");
        String tanggalakhir = getIntent ( ).getStringExtra ("tanggalakhir");

        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ( ).getReference ( );
        DatabaseReference pendingRef = db.child ("Users").child ("Pending");


        Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey ()
                .startAt ("*" + tanggalawal)
                .endAt ("*" + tanggalakhir + "\uf8ff");

        recView = (RecyclerView)findViewById (R.id.recview);
        recView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(queryByKey, Model.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new MyAdapter (options);
        recView.setAdapter (adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

and this is my adapter java

```
public class MyAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Model,MyAdapter.myViewHolder>{

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options) {
        super (options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Model model) {
        myViewHolder.currentDate.setText (model.getCurrentDate ());
        myViewHolder.fullName.setText (model.getFullName ());
        myViewHolder.currentDateandTime.setText (model.getCurrentDateandTime ());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder (view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView currentDate, fullName, currentDateandTime;
        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            currentDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvTanggalPengajuan);
            fullName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvNama);
            currentDateandTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById (R.id.tvNomorkontrak);
        }
    }
    public interface OnNoteListener{

        void OnNoteListener(int position);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect this `.orderByChild ("DataPelanggan")` to do?

Comment: to take data inside of `DataPelanggan` folder, im using startAt for searching data base on date range, and it work already for taking the *20211113 thing, but i should take data inside DataPelanggan and show it in recycle view

Answer (score 0):

> [I expect] expect `.orderByChild ("DataPelanggan")` to take data inside of DataPelanggan folder and show it in recycle view

Firebase's `orderByChild` is an operation to order the data from the database on the property of each child node.

If you want to show the `DataPelanggan` of each selected child, you will have to read the entire child snapshot and then get its `child("DataPelanggan")`.

```
Query queryByKey = pendingRef.orderByKey()
  .startAt ("*" + tanggalawal)
  .endAt ("*" + tanggalakhir + "\uf8ff");

queryByKey.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot dataPelangganSnapshot = childSnapshot.child("DataPelanggan");
            Map<String,Object> values = dataPelangganSnapshot.getValue();
            String fullName = (String) values.get("fullName");
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't link to external code please. My answer explains why your code won't work (and should in fact show an exception), and how to read the data structure you showed. If you have a different setup than you initially showed us (as seems to be the case from using FirebaseUI in the link), edit your question to show that. Going forward, I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to prevent this sort of confusion.

Comment: i've add some code more in the top, for my case